# Separate date from a column and store in a new column

Tags: r, date, as.date

I am trying to separate date from one column and trying to put the date in another column but the new column is horribly wrong when I compare the dates in both columns. I am attaching pic below. I am separating date from the `started_at` column and storing it in the `date` column.

[image]

The code I tried is in the image. For example in the 1st date in the `started_at` column is `"4/1/2019"` but when i separated it in a new column then it is returning `"0004-01-20"`.

I have tried using `format()` as well as `as.Date()` but it is also not giving the same value as in parent column `started_at`. Picture is attached below.

[image]

Comment: `as.Date("4/1/2019", format="%d/%m/%Y")`

Comment: Hi Ahmad, welcome to stack overflow. Please provide data in a copy-pasteable format, eg by using `dput()`, [not as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/17303805). Also have a look at [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/17303805). Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have found the solution. SOLUTION:  all_trips$Date <- format(as.Date(all_trips$started_at, format = "%d/%m/%Y"), "%Y-%m-%d") We had to tell the as.Date function our current date is in which format and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the format is not working, but as string variable, you could just:

```
stringsplit(all_trips$started_at, " " )
```

Or with tidyr:

```
all_trips <- tidyr::separate(all_trips, started_at, c("date", "hour"), sep = " ")
```

In stringr:

```
all_trips[c("date", "hour")] <- str_split_fixed(all_trips$started_at," ", 2)
```

Comment: I have found the solution. SOLUTION:                                                          all_trips$Date <- format(as.Date(all_trips$started_at, format = "%d/%m/%Y"), "%Y-%m-%d")      We had to tell the as.Date function our current date is in which format and that's it.